# How to set the localization of the application without changing the current page?

Tags: jsp, localization, struts2

I am using locale on my application, it perfectly works, but the problem is that, when I am in the main page (index.jsp) when I click on a specific language in different pages of the application, it goes to index.jsp page, how can I change the mapping so when I select a specific language in a page it stays in that page and change the language of the application ? please let me know if you need me to upload any other part of the code.

Struts.xml

```
<action name="locale" class="com.myapp.struts.LocaleAction">
  <result name="SUCCESS" type="tiles">baseLayout</result>
</action>
```

Action

```
public class LocaleAction extends ActionSupport{

    @Override
    public String execute(){
        return "SUCCESS";
    }
}
```

Comment: I think we'll need to see more of your configuration. What you explain is not typical, so you're doing something interesting to produce this effect. A users locale should already be determined by their browser, a user would not typically be changing the locale in the middle of your site, although it shouldn't make a difference. The locale will be picked up in several different ways how exactly are you manually overriding the defaults?

Comment: It seems you locale action does nothing with locale. Show me the code how do you change the locale.

Answer (score 3):

The `default` interceptor stack includes an `i18n` interceptor that watches for the `request_locale` parameter and changes locale based on that parameter. So there is no need for *special* action.

For staying in the same page use `<s:url>` tag with `includeParams="all"` and empty `value` attribute.

```
<s:url var="urlen" includeParams="all" value="">
  <s:param name="request_locale">en</s:param>
</s:url>
```