# how to redirect user to previous page

Tags: jsp, struts2

After user selects language I want to redirect him to previous page. But when I try to run below code it continues to call request. Is there any way to do this?

My language selection;

```
<s:url id="indexEN" namespace="/" action="locale" >
    <s:param name="request_locale" >en_US</s:param>
</s:url>
<s:url id="indexBR" namespace="/" action="locale" >
    <s:param name="request_locale" ></s:param>
</s:url>
<s:a href="%{indexEN}" >English</s:a>
<s:a href="%{indexBR}" >Brs</s:a>
```

Here is my struts.xml

```
    <package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
      <action name="locale" class="myutils.LocaleAction">
        <result name="input">${Url}</result>
      </action>
    </package>
```

my LocaleAction.java

```
public class LocaleAction extends ActionSupport {

  private String Url;

  //business logic
  public String execute() {
      return INPUT;
  }

  public String getUrl() {
      HttpServletRequest request = ServletActionContext.getRequest();
      Url  = request.getRequestURI();
      return Url;
  }
}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/15582074/1700321.

Comment: @AleksandrM Do I need to change getUrl method? It still continues to call request url.

Comment: Don't call your `locale` action at all. Use the code from linked answer.

Comment: @AleksandrM If I don't call my locale action How can I save user's language selection in session? I must use locale action or something else.

Comment: Why do you need to save it in session by yourself?

Comment: There is no point in downvoting my answer. If you don't understand how S2 works then ask questions.

Comment: @AleksandrM I need to save it in session by myself because "your answer doesn't save user's locale in session". When I go to another page It returns to default locale. This is why I need to save it in sesion.

Comment: S2 saves locale in session. See `i18n` interceptor.

Comment: @AleksandrM If you didn't write your own locale action it doesn't save locale in session. Look at this example http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-i18n-or-localization-example/

Comment: From your link: *To change the default locale, you just need to declared a “request_locale” parameter, set your prefer language code and pass to an Action class. In Struts 2 the com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor interceptor, which declared in the struts-default.xml, will hijack your Action class and handle the locale stuff accordingly.*

Comment: The `LocaleAction` and `locale` method is just an example. Just try my solution and it will work.

Comment: @AleksandrM As I said earlier your method doesn't work. If it works for you there must be something different with my project. I gave upvote for you answer.

Comment: Show your interceptor stack, maybe problem is there.